# Agregar una fila a una columna mediante una metrica con POWER BI

Tags: powerbi

Tengo una tabla con 2 campos como se muestra en la imagen. Lo que deseo hacer es agregar una metrica, la cual suma el valor de A, B, C y lo asignarlo a un nuevo registro de categoria "D".

Utilizando el lenguaje DAX en POWER BI

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: te comento que Power Bi no permite inserción de datos. Solamente leerá datos de las fuentes y puede generar medidas o columnas, pero no insertará filas. Lo ideal sería que modifiques desde el origen esos datos. Sino puedes agregar un "Total" a la tabla para que los sume automáticamente y muestre dicho resultado o construir una visualización aparte tipo etiqueta que tenga la suma de ellos por separado de la tabla. Saludos,

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/). - [Desde revisión](/review/low-quality-posts/168255)